# lldb - Couldn't resolve the class for an Objective-C static method call

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

What's wrong with lldb? Was doing it many times but now does not work. (Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7.0-beta)

```
(lldb) po [UIApplication sharedApplication]
Error [IRForTarget]: Couldn't resolve the class for an Objective-C static method call
error: 0 errors parsing expression
error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target

(lldb) p @[@"", @""]
Error [IRForTarget]: Couldn't resolve the class for an Objective-C static method call
error: 0 errors parsing expression
error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target

(lldb) po @[@"", @""]
Error [IRForTarget]: Couldn't resolve the class for an Objective-C static method call
error: 0 errors parsing expression
error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target

(lldb) e id $a = @[@"11"]
Error [IRForTarget]: Couldn't resolve the class for an Objective-C static method call
error: 0 errors parsing expression
error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target
```

> update

Maybe it was a problem with my iPod touch on ios 9.0 beta but on mine colleague's iPad with ios 8.4 all work well.
The problem has been solved.

Comment: What is the code causing this issue ?

Comment: It's Xcode debugger, just wanna see a value of the application's instance. The Application is just empty template from Xcode's starting templates. After setup a breakpoint you could use the lldb tool to see the runtime of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I find  Xcode settting:Targets->build Settings->Mach-O Type, change Dynamic Library to Static Library. It should work.